# url in xml site map, I don't get it

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

inside my urlset I've come to urls like:

```
<url>
<loc>http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com%2F1-5%2Findex-3.html</loc>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.700</priority>
</url>
```

If I copy paste that url doesn't work, I'm doing this via php with the urls:

```
$durl=utf8_encode(urlencode($durl));
```

`utf8_encode` first and then `urlencode`

is this correct?

Comment: Why are you using `utf8_encode`? `urlencode` should be enough

Comment: cause I read must be entity escaped (urlencode) and utf8_encoded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/urlencode) is a way of converting a URL to be used in the query string or other url-sensitive areas - when you *don't* want the url parsed by the browser. Your goal here is to print the actual URL because that's what the sitemap parser wants.

You can the keep the utf8-encode but it's not likely needed if you're already doing things using utf8.

Just use `$durl=utf8_encode($durl);`

Comment: ok, but they say that the url must be entity escaped like & to &amp; http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#escaping still yes urlencode messes the url completely.